# Loading applications with .NET bundled inside?

Tags: c#, .net, build, virtualization

I've seen loads of examples on virtualization. PostBuild does exactly what I am trying to achieve.

It bundles the .NET Framework into the executable being run, so that it doesn't need the .NET Framework to run at all. Bad thing is that the size of the file is around 50 megabytes though, but that doesn't matter to me.

How can I do the same virtualization stuff as PostBuild can do for me, with my application in .NET? A commercial solution is not an option here.

Comment: Commercial solutions come in many flavors: Some charge royalties, some don't.  Some have free editions, some don't.  Some include source code, some don't.  Please be specific about your requirements.

Comment: There are commercial products that do this, called ".NET linker".  They have mostly disappeared or haven't kept up with .NET releases, I think Salamander might still be around.  Sticker shock on the license fee is high.  It makes little sense to spend the money with .NET preinstalled since Vista and the .NET 3.5 SP1 bootstrapper requiring very little overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ILMerge: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Comment: Doesn't ILMerge just package a bunch of assemblies together? You still need .NET installed, right?